# Is a function inverse an intrinsic property of a function?

Tags: proof-writing, inverse-function

Often when writing proofs, I'll define a function $f$ pointwise

For example, given a set $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and a set $B = \{1, 2, 3\}$, I might define a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ as follows:

$f(a) = 1$

$f(b) = 2$

$f(c) = 3$

Now let's say in my proof I need to use some property of $f^{-1}$

Clearly $f^{-1}$ exists. But I get hung up on the language around introducing it.

I guess I see my options for the structure of my proof as:

> `<Introduce/define f pointwise>.` Now we define $f^{-1}$

But we can't actually define $f^{-1}$ because function inverses are unique in general, so this is wrong.

In practice this is what I usually do is:

> `<Introduce/define f pointwise>`.  Now, given `<property I need>` of $f^{-1}$, `<move on with my proof/life>`

But this also makes me uneasy -- so far I've only explicitly defined two sets, $A$ and $B$, and a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$.

In other words, assuming it exists, is $f^{-1}$ an essential property of $f$ that is implied to be present in the universe of objects accessible to my proof (is it "in scope" within my proof, to use computer science terminology) from the moment I define $f$?

What is the correct language to use here when introducing $f^{-1}$ (when its existence has already been established)?

Comment: The unique inverse’s existence is already implied if  $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Every bijection $f$ has an unique inverse $f^{-1}$ and every injective function F has a left inverse g. If the existence of the inverse is guaranteed, you can just say ' Now we take $f^{-1}$'